# what is the meaning of go-to and move-from in the below?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of go-to and move-from in the below?

> Like McCann (215), we found the positive and the negative experiences triggered either a go-to or a move-from mind-set.

former it says: a go-to mind-set, where your central motivation is to win, and a move from mind-set, where your biggest driver is a fear of failure

I found these meaning for *go-to* in a dictionary:

> 1. being a person who can be turned to for expert knowledge, advice, or reliable performance, especially in a crucial situation.
> 2. (in team sports) being a player who can be relied on to score, especially at a crucial time in the game.
>
> [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/go-to) from *The Random House Dictionary*

Comment: Presumably "move-from" (not an "established" usage) is a nonce coinage intended as an antonym to "go-to" - the *precise* meaning of which will be context-dependent. So without more context it's anybody's guess (and even *with* full context, it's essentially a matter of opinion, since there's no generally-accepted dictionary definition).

Comment: I think we cannot say more about what is meant, unless we know what subject matter McCann (215) was about.  Perhaps a "go-to mind-set" is a mind-set that prefers going to (something), while s "move-from mind-set" is a mind-set that prefers moving from (something).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Like McCann (215), we found the positive and the negative experiences triggered either a go-to or a move-from mind-set.

This use is attempting to contrast the difference(s) between proactive mindset (taking action to achieve something: **go-to**) or simply a reactive one (taking action to avoid something: **move-from**).

Comment: Thank you Davo, your question is great, but can you explain me more about it? thank you

Comment: I think we cannot say more about what is meant, unless we know what subject matter McCann (215) was about.

Comment: yes, it says "a go-to mind-set, where your central motivation is to win, and a move from mind-set, where your biggest driver is a fear of failure."